# How to check if a shell command is running from PHP

Tags: php

EDIT: I have this but still not working; I am trying to get this to check to see if that command is running. Thanks

```
    function command_exist($cmd) {
    $return = shell_exec(sprintf("which %s", escapeshellarg($cmd)));
    return !empty($return);
}
if (!command_exist('rtmpdump')) {
    print 'doesnt exist';
} else {
    echo ' exists ';
}
```

Comment: rather than using `which %s`, I suggest you combine `ps` with `grep` perhaps? I don't have time to cook up a full solution. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in the right direction I found something like this ; `ps -ef | grep $scriptname | grep -v grep;`
`if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then`
    `echo "PROCESS IS RUNNING";`
`fi` but not too sure how to implement it into the script; Plus this has script name not command not sure if they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php 
    function command_exist($cmd) {
        $return = shell_exec(sprintf("ps -ef | grep " . escapeshellarg($cmd) . " | grep -v grep"));
        return !empty($return);
    }
    $command = 'command here';
    if (!command_exist($command)) {
        print 'not running';
    } else {
       echo ' running ';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Mac

```
function command_exist($cmd) {
    $return = shell_exec(sprintf("which %s", escapeshellarg($cmd)));
    return !empty($return);
}
if (!command_exist('rtmpdump')) {
    print 'doesnt exist';
} else {
    shell_exec('rtmpdump');
}else {
    echo ' exists ';
}
```

I can suggested, you could simply use:

```
if (`which rtmpdump`) {
    shell_exec('rtmpdump');
}
```

Comment: this doesn't check to see if the command is actively being ran.